# How to edit an Embed Author?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to edit the author of an embed sent by my bot.
The message is sent by this code :

```
task_chan.send('', {
embed: {
      color: task_colors[0x808080],
      title: 'Tache n°1',
      thumbnail: {
         url: 'https://...'
      },
      author: {
         name: 'Tache à prendre',
         icon_url: 'https://zupimages.net/up/20/12/xqsf.jpg'
      },
      fields:[{
         name: "Tache à faire :",
         value: "...",
      },{
         name: 'Avancement de la tache :',
         value: 'Non commencée'
      }]
      }
})
```

To edit the message I've tried :

```
taken.embeds[0].author.icon_url = util.avatarURL
taken.embeds[0].author.name = util.username
taken.edit(new Discord.RichEmbed(taken.embeds[0]));
```

`taken` contain the message to edit and `util` an user.

And it only change the name…
I don't understand why but `author.icon_url` is undefined between these two code samples.

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

method `channel.send` return a `promise`, so you can use `.then(msg=>` to get a message object.

```js
let testEmbed = {
      color: task_colors[0x808080],
      title: 'Tache n°1',
      thumbnail: {
         url: 'https://...'
      },
      author: {
         name: 'Tache à prendre',
         icon_url: 'https://zupimages.net/up/20/12/xqsf.jpg'
      },
      fields:[{
         name: "Tache à faire :",
         value: "...",
      },{
         name: 'Avancement de la tache :',
         value: 'Non commencée'
      }]
      }
}

task_chan.send({embed:testEmbed}).then(msg => {
    testEmbed.name = 'LOL'
    testEmbed.iconURL = 'SOMEURL'
    msg.edit({embed:testEmbed})
})
```

I would recommend that you use the [built-in methods](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) for creating embeds, in my opinion it is more convenient.

Comment: I already use a `.then()` to save my message, I'm able to change the autor name, the fields, the color and the thumbnail but I can't edit the author icon_url with this method :/

Comment: why you can`t ?
My solution will work.. Or you need get message embed, and then edit some parts?

Comment: Yes `RichEmbed.autor.name = 'text'` works perfectly but I also want to change the author icon_url and I Don't kwon how to do it :/

Comment: @chbouli04 use `testEmbed.author.iconURL = 'SOMEURL'

Comment: Thank you ! That's exactly what I need :)

Comment: Well, then in this case, please mark the issue as resolved :) @chbouli04